# Use excel to generate table assignments for each person

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of 120 attendees. I would like to randomly assign each attendee to a table. There are 10 tables. I would like to ask Excel to generate a number, 1-10 for each attendee.

I realize that I can do this manually, but I need to do this for 13 different events.

Comment: Take a look at the =RANDBETWEEN() function.

Comment: Does each table have exactly 12 seats?

Comment: Can they be at the same tables for each event or must each event be unique?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a formula. You should consider adding an excel-vba and vba tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the list of 120 attendees in column `A`, starting at `A2`, enter this formula into `B2` and instead of hitting just <kbd>enter</kbd>, commit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
=LARGE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:120"))*NOT(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:120")))),RANDBETWEEN(1,121-ROW(B1)))
```

Then put this formula in `C2` (no need for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=MOD(B2,10)+1
```

Fill `B2` and `C2` down to row 121. Column `C` will have the random table assignments, with 12 assigned to each table. Get a new set of assignments by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/07/03/how-to-create-a-random-list-of-unique-numbers-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Enter this in a 1-column by 120-row range to get a list of 120 random table assignments, with each table number appearing exactly 12 times (commit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=MOD(ROUND(MOD(SMALL(RANDBETWEEN(0,1e12*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:120"))>0))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:120"))/1000,ROW(INDIRECT("1:120"))),1)*1000,0),10)+1
```

Get a new set of assignments by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: So which of your answers is correct/concise? I'll upvote the correct one and if _this_ one is "more correct" I would edit it to include your URL

Comment: @MarkStewart I'm not sure what you mean by my URL. I don't have a reference for this formula. I just thought of it this morning.

Comment: Sorry I meant mentioning the URL https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/07/03/how-to-create-a-random-list-of-unique-numbers-in-excel/ that gave some details on the steps.

Comment: @MarkStewart Gotcha. The link only applied to the first answer. That's why I didn't include it here.